# Connecting fields in two List of objects

Tags: apex, trigger, list, map, bulkification

I have two list of object.

`List<ClassA>` and `List <ClassB>`. ClassA has a field `TextA` and ClassB has a text field `TextB`. I want to copy the `TextB` value to `TextA` for each object of ClassA. Any idea how to go about this?

How do I loop through both ClassB and ClassA at the same time. I though of using Map but I am not sure how to go about forming key value pair here.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two objects? I should not have to say this at this point [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Map<String,String>` of linked fields and iterate that instead.

eg:

```
private static Map<String, String> mapFields = 
new Map<String, String> {'MailingState' => 'State__c', 
                         'MailingStreet' => 'Street__c', 
                         'MailingPostalCode' => 'Zip__c',
                         'MailingCity' => 'City__c'};
```

Then, iterate over the list of ObjectA (assuming that you want to copy the values to the corresponding ObjectB)

```
for (Integer i = 0; i< listOfObjectA.size; i++){
  ObjectA obA = listOfObjectA[i];
  ObjectB obB = listOfObjectB[i];
  //call your mapFields function:
  mapFields(obA,obB);
}
```

In the mapFields function, iterate over your mapFields, copying values:

```
for (String objAKey : mapFields.keySet()){
  //note, isBlank will only work for Strings - you will need to expand this
  if (!String.isBlank(obA.get(objAKey))){

    ObjAValue = obA.get(objAKey);
    ObjBKey = mapFields.get(objAKey);
    obB.put(ObjBKey,ObjAValue);

  }
}
```

Comment: clarified the last loop - it is a separate function or lives inside the first loop.

Comment: No probs - it's always a handy technique